# Using xpath with lxml.etree._ElementTree

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have an object arptree, I am trying to locate the mac-address of an ip-address, but failed.

```
>>> arptree 
<lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x0000000004641688>
```

When I try the following xpath, it returns an empty list

```
>>> arptree.xpath("descendant::mac-address[following-sibling::ip-address='10.69.119.150']")
[]
```

If I modify the xpath to exclude "='10.69.119.150'", it actually returns a list of Elements.

```
>>> arptree.xpath("descendant::mac-address[following-sibling::ip-address]")
```

[, , , , , , , , , ]

I can use a for loop to access the content. And I am sure the mac-address for ip-address 10.69.119.150 is there.

```
for elt in arptree.iter():
    print elt.tag, elt.text
```

The strange thing is that if I copy and paste the xml output to a xml file.
Then use:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse(open('arp.xml'))
tree.xpath("descendant::mac-address[following-sibling::ip-address='10.69.119.150']")
```

It will return the mac-address for the ip address.

I'm using Python 2.7.9 with lxml package.
Can anyone help?

Update 1: example XML

```
<arp-table-information>
<arp-table-entry>
    <mac-address>00:a0:a5:76:1a:96</mac-address>
    <ip-address>10.69.119.130</ip-address>
    <hostname>10.69.119.130</hostname>
    <interface-name>vlan.49</interface-name>
    <arp-table-entry-flags>
        <none/>
    </arp-table-entry-flags>
</arp-table-entry>
<arp-table-entry>
    <mac-address>00:0f:bb:c6:26:3d</mac-address>
    <ip-address>10.69.119.150</ip-address>
    <hostname>10.69.119.150</hostname>
    <interface-name>vlan.55</interface-name>
    <arp-table-entry-flags>
        <none/>
    </arp-table-entry-flags>
</arp-table-entry>
</arp-table-information>
```

Update 2: Please ignore Update 1

When I use

```
arptree = ex.device.rpc.get_arp_table_information().getroottree()
arptree.write('arptree.xml', pretty_print=True)
```

to save the ElementTree to a xml, the layout changes to

```
<arp-table-information style="normal">
<arp-table-entry>
<mac-address>
00:a0:a5:76:1a:96
</mac-address>
<ip-address>
10.69.119.130
</ip-address>
<hostname>
10.69.119.130
</hostname>
<interface-name>
vlan.49
</interface-name>
<arp-table-entry-flags>
<none/>
</arp-table-entry-flags>
</arp-table-entry>
<arp-table-entry>
<mac-address>
00:0f:bb:c6:26:3d
</mac-address>
<ip-address>
10.69.119.150
</ip-address>
<hostname>
10.69.119.150
</hostname>
<interface-name>
vlan.55
</interface-name>
<arp-table-entry-flags>
<none/>
</arp-table-entry-flags>
</arp-table-entry>
```

Maybe this is why the following code doesn't work???

```
arptree.xpath("descendant::mac-address[following-sibling::ip-address='10.69.119.150']")
```

Based on this xml file, can anyone help?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the XML?

Comment: how do you obtain your `arptree` in the first place? `fromstring`?

Comment: I will provide an example in the post

Comment: @Anzel I got the arptree using a Juniper PyEz package specific method. arptree = device.rpc.get_arp_table_information().getroottree(). The device.rpc.get_arp_table_information() itself returns an object of lxml.etree._Element

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce the problem using only lxml or do I need PyEz to do that?

Comment: @mzjn I think as long as you can construct an _Element, that would be fine

Comment: @yin_bill_wang, from that `arptree` object, can you do `etree.tostring(arptree)`, does it convert properly? If yes, simple way is to convert back to string and contruct the element with your `lxml` library using `fromstring`.

Comment: *as long as you can construct an _Element, that would be fine*. I don't understand. I can parse your XML sample without problems using lxml but I cannot reproduce the issue that the xpath returns an empty list.

Comment: @mzjn use the 2nd XML sample to reproduce the problem (need to add closing tag for `arp-table-information` to make it well-formed)

Comment: @mzjn Sorry for the confusion. When I tried on the XML in Update 1(copied directly from a switch console), everything is fine. But later, I found the XML is in the being stored is actually looks like Update2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 2nd XML, you have new line characters before and after the IP address value. You can use `normalize-space()` function to fix it :

```
descendant::mac-address[following-sibling::ip-address[normalize-space()='10.69.119.150']]
```

**working example for demo :**

```
from lxml import etree

xml = """<arp-table-information style="normal">
<arp-table-entry>
<mac-address>
00:a0:a5:76:1a:96
</mac-address>
<ip-address>
10.69.119.130
</ip-address>
<hostname>
10.69.119.130
</hostname>
<interface-name>
vlan.49
</interface-name>
<arp-table-entry-flags>
<none/>
</arp-table-entry-flags>
</arp-table-entry>
<arp-table-entry>
<mac-address>
00:0f:bb:c6:26:3d
</mac-address>
<ip-address>
10.69.119.150
</ip-address>
<hostname>
10.69.119.150
</hostname>
<interface-name>
vlan.55
</interface-name>
<arp-table-entry-flags>
<none/>
</arp-table-entry-flags>
</arp-table-entry>
</arp-table-information>"""

root = etree.fromstring(xml)
result = root.xpath("descendant::mac-address[following-sibling::ip-address[normalize-space()='10.69.119.150']]")
for r in result:
    print(etree.tostring(r))
```

**output :**

```
<mac-address>
00:0f:bb:c6:26:3d
</mac-address>
```